# How to prevent text from overflowing div container

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to prevent text from overflowing its div container without using white-space:normal?

Answer (score 2):

Use the overflow css property. It has four properties you can choose from, hidden, auto, scroll and visibile.

```
.overflow-text{
  //option 1
  overflow: hidden;
  //option 2
  overflow: auto;
  //option 3
  overflow: scroll;
  //option 4
  overflow: visible;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
```